# Ruby unpack file compressed in snappy framing format *.sz

Tags: ruby, snappy

I need to unpack snappy *.sz files in Ruby.

Format specification is here:
https://github.com/google/snappy/blob/master/framing_format.txt

I have found 2 gems so far.

https://github.com/miyucy/snappy - seems to be completely useless.

https://github.com/willglynn/snappy-ruby - is able to unpack separate snappy chunks but not the whole framing snappy file.

**QUESTION:**
Is there a working ruby gem that would allow me to do something like:

```
framing_snappy.unpack('filename.sz')
```

or the only way is write own code that will parse bytes and mess with bitwise shifts?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone is facing similar issue.
I finally came up with **[this code](https://gist.github.com/ludenus/90b07292ecbd61c67367d9ba6b465253)** and it seems to be working.